# Time-shifting property of Fourier transform -- why can't I take the exponential inside the transform?

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

The time-shifting property of the Fourier transform (see for example [the Wikipedia Fourier Transform article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Properties_of_the_Fourier_transform)) means that if $h(x) = f(x-x_0)$ then:

$$ 
\hat{h}(\xi) = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}\hat{f}(\xi)
$$

If I expand out the right-hand side using the definition of $\hat{f}$:

$$
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}\hat{f}(\xi) = \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi\xi x }\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

I notice that the exponential term in front of the integral is not a function of $x$ so I bring it inside the integral:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi\xi x }\,\mathrm{d}x & =
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}f(x)\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi\xi x }\,\mathrm{d}x \\
& = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left[\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}f(x)\right]\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi\xi x }\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{aligned}
$$

Now I would like to claim that the final expression on the right-hand side is just
$\hat{f}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}f(x)\right)$ so that:

$$
\hat{h}(\xi)=\hat{f}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}f(x)\right)
$$

Then I would like to claim that if I take the inverse transform of both sides I get:

$$
h(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}f(x)\quad (\, = f(x-x_0))
$$

But this seems to produce the wrong outcome when I calculate the modulus of $f(x-x_0)$.  For a concrete example, let $f(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-x^2}$.  Then:

$$|f(x)|^2 = (\mathrm{e}^{-x^2})^2$$

and

$$|f(x-x_0)|^2 = (\mathrm{e}^{-(x-x_0)^2})^2 = (\mathrm{e}^{{-x_0}^2+2xx_0})^2 (\mathrm{e}^{-x^2})^2 \ne |f(x)|^2
$$

but using the alternative expression I derived for $f(x-x_0)$:

$$|\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}f(x)|^2 = |\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}|^2|f(x)|^2 = |f(x)|^2$$

What mistake am I making here?

Comment: When you evaluate the inverse Fourier transform $h(x)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}\, \hat{f}(\xi)\, e^{2 i \pi \xi  x} \, d\xi=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \hat{f}(\xi)\, e^{2 i \pi \xi  \left(x-x_0\right)} \, d\xi$, the $\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}$ term is integrated out since it is a function of $\xi$ which is the integration variable.

Comment: Thank you @StevenClark.  That makes sense; after an inverse Fourier transform there should be no $\xi$ terms left in the expression.  There is one in the expression I derived and therefore it must be incorrect.  It does mess with my intuition though.  Nomally the inverse transform undoes the transform.  Perhaps that only works when the original expression doesn't involve $\xi$?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with interpreting the expression $\hat{f}(e^{-i2\pi x_0 \xi} f(x))$ is that $x$ is the variable in the time domain, not the frequency domain.  There is no "$x$" in the expression for $\hat{h}(\xi)$.  It disappears after the integration over $x$.  (That's not the case with $x_0$ because it was a constant.)

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer.  $\hat{f}$ is an integral over $x$, so the $x$ terms will disappear.  Explicitly including the argument of the resulting function: $\hat{f}(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}2\pi x_0 \xi}f(x))(\xi)$.  Perhaps I am still missing something.

Comment: I take your point though that the notation is unhelpful (and perhaps even wrong).  I am more used to $\tilde{s}(\omega) = F[s(t)](\omega) = (1/\sqrt{2\pi}) \int{s(t) \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}\omega t} \mathrm{d}t}$ and $s(t) = F^{-1}[\tilde{s}(\omega)](t) =  (1/(\sqrt{2\pi})) \int{\tilde{s}(\omega) \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\omega t} \mathrm{d}\omega}$.

Comment: Yes, I think using $F$ like you did above, makes more explicit when you're talking about a map between time and frequency domain functions, versus the functions $s(t)$ and $\hat{s}(w)$ themselves.